# how to reorder bars in a funnel chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, bar-chart, geom-bar

I want to draw a funnel chart but all the bars are not sorted correctly.

```
funnel_dt <- read.csv2("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Deborah-Jia/Complete_Analysis_da2/main/funnel_dt.csv")

funnel_dt %>% ggplot(aes(x = district, y = N, fill = covid)) +   # Fill column
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = .6) +   # draw the bars
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = brks, labels = lbls) + # Labels 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks= seq(1,23,1) ,labels=paste0("district ", as.character(seq(1, 23, 1)))) +
  coord_flip() +  # Flip axes
  labs(title="") +
  theme_tufte() +  # Tufte theme from ggfortify
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = .5), 
        axis.ticks = element_blank()) +   # Centre plot title
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2")  # Color palette
```

The plot is rather messy.
[image]

How to put the longest bars (district 11, 13, etc) in the bottom? I tried `reorder` but it doesn't work

Comment: How did you try `reorder`? Since you've got positive and negative numbers but want to order by total length, I would think `reorder(district, N, function(x) sum(abs(x)))` would work.

Comment: I use `reorder(N, district)` after `coord_flip() + `, it said `Discrete value supplied to continuous scale`. I also tried yours `ggplot(aes(x = reorder(district, N, function(x) sum(abs(x))), y = N, fill = covid))` same error. did I put it wrong?

Comment: That issue is that you have `scale_x_continuous` but your x values (District) are discrete, not continuous. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You've got positive and negative numbers but want to order by total length, so we need to sum the absolute values and order by that:

```
funnel_dt <- read.csv2("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Deborah-Jia/Complete_Analysis_da2/main/funnel_dt.csv")

funnel_dt %>% 
  mutate(district = reorder(district, N, function(x) -sum(abs(x)))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = district, y = N, fill = covid)) +   # Fill column
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = .6) +   # draw the bars
  #scale_y_continuous(breaks = brks, labels = lbls) + # Labels 
  scale_x_discrete(labels = function(d) paste("District", d)) +
  coord_flip() +  # Flip axes
  labs(title="") +
  #theme_tufte() +  # Tufte theme from ggfortify
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = .5), 
        axis.ticks = element_blank()) +   # Centre plot title
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Dark2")  # Color palette
```

I commented out the `y` scale because I don't have the `brks` and `labels`, but your `x` scale (which is flipped to become vertical) is discrete, not continuous - and be careful overriding labels and setting breaks manually, which can override the ordering. I left the breaks off and used an anonymous function for `labels` to paste on "District".

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I used `pivot_wider` to get the column `covid` into two columns

```
funnel_dt1 <- tidyr::pivot_wider(funnel_dt, names_from = 'covid', values_from = 'N')
funnel_dt1 <- funnel_df1[order(funnel_df1$after),]

funnel_dt1$district <- paste(rep('district ',nrow(funnel_dt1)), funnel_dt1$district)

funnel_df1 %>% ggplot(aes(x = reorder(district, -after))) +   # Fill column
  geom_bar(aes(y = before), fill = 'green', stat = "identity", width = .6) +
  geom_bar(aes(y = after), fill = 'red', stat = "identity", width = .6) +
  scale_x_discrete(labels = function(x) paste("District", x)) +
  coord_flip() +  # Flip axes
  labs(title="") +
  # theme_tufte() +  # Tufte theme from ggfortify
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = .5), 
        axis.ticks = element_blank())    # Centre plot title
```